# ng-init with function and variable initialization

Tags: angularjs

How can I achieve below given code correctly in angular js, here I want to execute loader method and initialize some variables.

```
ng-init="loader()" data-ng-init="firstName='John'"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 ng-init="loader(); firstName = 'John'"
```

But ng-init should almost always never used. Just move these instructions to your controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    // ...

    loader();
    $scope.firstName = 'John';
});
```